# Grouping with linq; But with conditions 

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I am having trouble wrapping my head on how to group a list of these classes.

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public long OrderClassId { get; set; }
    public int OrderTypeId { get; set; }
    public int OrderSubTypeId { get; set; }
    public string OrderString { get; set; }
    //.. other Order stuff not relevant to question
}
```

The basic grouping I understand. It looks like this (assume `orders` is a `List<Order>`):

```
var orderGroups = orders.GroupBy(x=>x.OrderClassId);

// Code to assign a unique OrderString to each group goes here
```

However, orders that have the same OrderClassId and have an OrderTypeId of 123 and have the same OrderSubTypeId need to have different OrderString values.

That is a bit confusing, so here is an example:

```
var order1 = new Order
                    {
                        OrderId = 1,
                        OrderClassId = 8754,
                        OrderTypeId = 123,
                        OrderSubTypeId = 7156
                    };

var order2 = new Order
                    {
                        OrderId = 2,
                        OrderClassId = 8754,
                        OrderTypeId = 123,
                        OrderSubTypeId = 7156
                    };

var order3 = new Order
                    {
                        OrderId = 3,
                        OrderClassId = 8754,
                        OrderTypeId = 951,
                        OrderSubTypeId = 35144
                    };
```

With my grouping, all of these would get the same `OrderString`.  But I need `order2` to get a different `OrderString`.

Is that possible using linq?  Or am I just going to have to iterate all the rows and manually separate the ones that match my criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Use anonymous type, e.g.:

```
var orderGroups = orders.GroupBy(x => new {Property1, Property2});
```

Comment: But I need to make sure that I only do the logic for OrderTypeId and OrderSubTypeId when OrderTypeId == 123

Answer (score 2):

You can do conditions as you generate the keys.

```
var groups = orders.GroupBy(x => new
{
  x.OrderClassId,
  TypeChoice = (x.OrderTypeId == 123) // ? true : false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you could use (OrderId is unique, right?):

```
orders.GroupBy(o => 
  new {
    o.OrderClassId,
    OrderIdSel = o.OrderTypeId == 123 ? o.OrderId : -1
  } )
```

Comment: This is closer than the others.  But it does not distinguish between rows with the same and different OrderSubTypeId values.  (Remember that I need to NOT group orders with other orders that have OrderTypeId = 123 AND have the OrderSubTypeId.)  Your example would separate all items that have OrderTypeId = 123.

Comment: It's really hard to get (as you already said). You want to separate 'orders that have the same OrderClassId and have an OrderTypeId of 123 and have the same OrderSubTypeId'. That sounds like: separate them, period. But what do you mean by 'AND have the OrderSubTypeId'?

Answer (score 1):

As Kirill says just use 
`var orderGroups = orders.GroupBy(x => new { x.OrderClassId, x.OrderSubTypeId });`

Comment: But I need to make sure that I only do the logic for OrderTypeId and OrderSubTypeId when OrderTypeId == 123